# Summing in a Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, case

I have a code where I am using a case when statement to select all the data for specific calendar years, and i need to sum all the hours accumulated for learning in that year and I have the code set up like:

```
SELECT  rg.JOB_GRP_CD,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EMP_TNG_STT_DT BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31' THEN 'ST_HOURS_SUM' ELSE 0 END) AS 2010_Hours
FROM dbo.COL_TBL_TRN_RESULTS_GEMS rg
INNER JOIN dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail gd
    ON rg.JOB_GRP_CD = gd.JOB_GRP_CD 
    AND rg.EMP_TNG_STT_DT = gd.REC_EFF_STT_DT
GROUP BY rg.JOB_GRP_CD
```

I keep getting an unable to parse query text error. The `ST_HOURS_SUM` is what I need to be totaled up for each person for the 2010 year. `ST_SUM_HOURS` is a column containing hours for certain training and i need them summed for each employee for the set year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said remove the quotes, & you can't have a column alias beginning with a digit; escape it:

```
...ELSE 0 END) AS [2010_Hours]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT dbo.COL_TBL_TRN_RESULTS_GEMS.JOB_GRP_CD, SUM(CASE WHEN EMP_TNG_STT_DT BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31' THEN ST_HOURS_SUM ELSE 0 END) AS [2010_Hours]
FROM  dbo.COL_TBL_TRN_RESULTS_GEMS INNER JOIN
               dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail ON dbo.COL_TBL_TRN_RESULTS_GEMS.JOB_GRP_CD = dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.JOB_GRP_CD AND 
               dbo.COL_TBL_TRN_RESULTS_GEMS.EMP_TNG_STT_DT = dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.REC_EFF_STT_DT
GROUP BY dbo.COL_TBL_TRN_RESULTS_GEMS.JOB_GRP_CD
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `'` in `THEN 'ST_HOURS_SUM' ELSE 0 END`. This way "ST_HOURS_SUM" is a string and not the column name. Remove the `'` and it should work.

Comment: It did not work, I have always written the codes like this so this is confusing